# Function defined by its own integral at a given point.

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

If $y=f(x)$ is a differentiable function such that

$$f(x)=x+ \int_0^1x^2zf(z)dz + \int_0^1xz^2f(z)dz$$ Then what is the value of $f\left(\frac{-9}{4}\right)$

The options were

(A)$\frac{-4}{9}$  (B)$\frac{4}{9}$
(C)$-1$ (D)$0$

First I tried differentiating with respect to $x$. I believe we can take out the x terms from definite integral. I could not deduce anything meaningful from it.
Hence I assumed $x=z$ , but solving required the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, which is not given in the question.

How can this question be solved?

NOTE:$z$ is NOT a complex variable.

Comment: Did you try integrating over the same interval instead? This should give you a relation between $\int_0^1 f(x) dx, \int_0^1 x f(x) dx$ and $\int_0^1 x^2f(x) dx$, which may be a start. Maybe even multiply by x or x^2 beforehand to get enough equations.

Comment: @mlk That did the trick. Thanks a lot  for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straight forward way:

From the formula you have $f$ is in the form
$$
f(x)=ax+bx^2
$$
with
$$
a=1+\int_0^1 z^2f(z)\,dz\quad \text{and}\quad b=\int_0^1zf(z)\,dz.
$$
Now, just plug that into the integrals and you you have
$$
a=1+\int_0^1 z^2(az+bz^2)\,dz\quad \text{and}\quad b=\int_0^1z(az+bz^2)\,dz.
$$
Just calculate, and solve for $a$ and $b$. Then you know $f$, and can just plug $-9/4$ into the formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle a=\int_0^1zf(z)dz$ and $\displaystyle b=\int_0^1z^2f(z)dz$. Then

$$f(x)=ax^2+(b+1)x$$

We have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1zf(z)dz&=\int_0^1[az^3+(b+1)z^2]dz\\
a&=\left[\frac{az^4}{4}+\frac{(b+1)z^3}{3}\right]_0^1\\
a&=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b+1}{3}\\
\frac{3a}{4}&=\frac{b+1}{3}\\
b+1&=\frac{9a}{4}
\end{align*}

So

$$f(x)=ax^2+\frac{9a}{4}x$$

$$f\left(\frac{-9}{4}\right)=a\left(\frac{-9}{4}\right)^2+\frac{9a}{4}\left(\frac{-9}{4}\right)=0$$